# openMP increment add int among threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, openmp

Hye

I'm trying to multithread the function below. I fail to get the counter to be properly shared among OpenMP threads, I tried atomic and int, atomic seem to not be working, neither do INT. Not sure, I'm lost, how can I solve this?

```
  std::vector<myStruct> _myData(100);
    int counter;
    counter =0
    int index;
#pragma  omp parallel for private(index)
    for (index = 0; index < 500; ++index) {
        if (data[index].type == "xx") {
            myStruct s;
            s.innerData = data[index].rawData
            processDataA(s); // processDataA(myStruct &data)
            processDataB(s);
            _myData[counter++] = s; // each thread should have unique int not going over 100 of initially allocated items in _myData
        }
    }
```

Edit. Update bad syntax/missing parts

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you chose to have the index private?

Comment: Does not compile. Is `inxed` supposed to be `index`? Please post a [MCVE]

Comment: It seems a typical example explaining why you need critical sections. By the way, using `counter` without initializing is bad.

Comment: You need to describe more clearly what the intended behavior is and what *seems not to be working* means. Particularly, must the result in `_myData` be deterministically ordered? Also, what is `myStruct`, and how expensive are `processData{A,B}`. Knowing that is essential to give a recommendation with reasonable performance.

Comment: @MikeCAT If data race involves only `counter`, I would prefer using _atomic operations_ instead of _critical sections_. Namely, `int temp; #pragma omp atomic capture { temp = counter++; } _myData[temp] = s;`.

Comment: Hey, sorry to all, it was late when I posted it and I miss-checked it. I have updated the example code to be more "accurate", thank you for your time & help.

Comment: @DanielLangr I looks perfect but I think I can't use with the msvs as its limited to 2.0 openMP I think there is reduction(+:sum) but I haven't had luck in implementing that yet.

Comment: @Dariusz Then, you can use `#pragma omp critical` plus `temp = counter++` on the next line. Always put into critical sections only minimal required code. Also, you might want to use `schedule(dynamic)` and maybe also experiment with chunk sizes, since there can happen load balancing issues due to `if` condition within the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use OpenMP `atomic capture`, I would try:

```
std::vector<myStruct> _myData(100);
int counter = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)
for (int index = 0; index < 500; ++index) {
   if (data[index].type == "xx") {
      myStruct s;
      s.innerData = data[index].rawData
      processDataA(s); 
      processDataB(s);
      int temp;
      #pragma omp critical
      temp = counter++;
      assert(temp < _myData.size());
      _myData[temp] = s; 
   }
}
```

Or:

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic,c)
```

and experiment with chunk size `c`.

However, atomics would be likely more efficient than critical sections. There should be some form of atomics supported by your compiler.

---

Note that your solution is kind of fragile, since it works only if the condition inside the loop is evaluated to `true` less than 101x. That's why I added assertion into the code. Maybe a better solution:

```
std::vector<myStruct> _myData;
size_t size = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+,size)
for (int index = 0; index < data.size(); ++index)
   if (data[index].type == "xx") size++;
v.resize(size);
...
```

Then, you don't need to care about the vector size and also don't waste memory space.